# The Most Dangerous Gameshow in the world

Tags: lateral-thinking

You are a contestant on the most dangerous gameshow in the world (lucky you!).

The host presents you with three doors.  You're told that:

1. Behind the first door, there is deadly poisonous gas.
2. Behind the second door, there are trained assassins with knives.
3. Behind the third door, there are lions which have not eaten in years.

Which door should you open and why?

Comment: Ah, honest mistake, sorry.

Comment: Is that classic to note as duplicate of a downvoted question? The linked question is `-3` and has a suspicion of being a duplicate...

Comment: Also, as I cannot delete this as it is marked as a duplicate of another, I encourage anyone seeing this to add their downvote to my question.  Lets punish users who are genuinely trying to contribute to the community, *together*!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My pick.

> Door 3. Lions which have not eaten in years would be dead lions.